# Is 'x=+1 or x=-1' $\iff$ '(x+1)(x-1)=0' correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, quadratics

I am quite certain that **'x=+1 or x=-1' $\impliedby$ '(x+1)(x-1)=0'** is true (you use this principle when solving quadratic equations).

However, I am less secure in affirming that  **'x=+1 or x=-1'$\implies$ '(x+1)(x-1)=0'** is also true (if it is true, then you can say 'x=+1 or x=-1' $\iff$ '(x+1)(x-1)=0' overall as suspected in my main question).

I am not sure if this **latter** statement is correct because when you substitute **x=+1** in the first bracket (x+1)and **x=-1** in the second bracket (x-1) of the expression (x+1)(x-1) the result becomes (+1+1)(-1-1) = -4 which clearly is **not 0**. This is different to when you substitute **x=-1** in the first bracket and **x=+1** in the second bracket where the result becomes (-1+1)(1-1) = **0**.

Hence, it appears that actually 'x=+1 or x=-1' does not imply '(x+1)(x-1)=0' (because there are cases where it equals 4 instead). Therefore,  only **'x=+1 or x=-1' $\impliedby$ '(x+1)(x-1)=0'** is true and this is our end statement.

Am I right in believing this?

Comment: If $x=1$ then $x \neq -1$. It can't be both at the same time.

Comment: Why would you substitute $x=1$ in the first bracket but $x=-1$ in the second? Then, you shouldn't write both of them as $x$; they are not equal.

Comment: Other than that, the iff claim is correct. $$x=1~\lor~x=-1\iff x-1=0~\lor~x+1=0\iff (x-1)(x+1)=0$$ since a product is $0$ iff one of its factors is $0$

Comment: Your title says $(x+1)(y-1)=0$. Is this a typo?

Comment: @Sandejo Yes, I have corrected it - thank you!

Comment: @CyclotomicField Of course, that makes so much more sense! I forgot that x=1 and x=-1 represent two different cases whilst the expression (x+1)(x-1) represents only a single case. Thank you.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas Yes, this makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you write $ P \; or Q \; $, this means that we have may be $ P $, may be $ Q$ and may be both.

for example
$$x>0 \; or\; x <2$$

But in your case, you cannot have $ P: x=1$ and $ Q:x=-1$.

You should write $$x=1 \;xor\;x=-1\iff (x-1)(x+1)=0$$
"xor" is the exclusive disjunction.

Comment: While you are correct that x = 1 xor x = -1 <==> (x + 1)(x – 1) = 0 is a more precise statement, x = 1 or x = -1 <==> (x + 1)(x – 1) = 0 is still correct. It is not necessary for "P and Q" to be possible in order for "P or Q" to be true.